# Increase in firebase reads react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im new to firebase and i think i'm doing something wrong when i call a function that sets the state values i get a 2k read in my firestore database. The function is used to display users in a table and i want it to re render when a new student is added hence the useEffect hook.

When i remove the users from the useEffect hook the reads go back to normal.

```js
const getUsers = () => {
  db.collection('students').doc(auth.user.uid).collection('studentList')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const userList = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const data = doc.data()
            userList.push(data)
        })
        setUsers(userList)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    getUsers()
}, [users])
```

Comment: `getUsers` is responsible for **setting** `users` and you're calling it inside an `useEffect` with `users` in dependency array. It's an infinite trigger. Find a way such that `getUsers` is called inside an `useEffect` with empty dependency array. This will require you to register a firebase event handler to give you latest data whenever something changes at server side. All this will go inside `getUsers` only.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Thanks for explanation but how do you actually do it?

Comment: Explore https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen. The `onSnapshot` listener will do your bit.